# problem launching the .BAT file for tmodlauncher

Tags: batch-file

When running the `.BAT` file to start, I get this:

```
[31mIt has been detected that your installation directory contains third-party library files[0m
[31mthat could potentially break tModLoader. If you have previously installed other tModLoader editions[0m
[31m- we recommend you to redownload them and install them into a folder separate from tModLoader\'s.[0m
[31mFor example: 'steamapps/common/tModLoader64bit' (placed next to the 'Terraria' directory.)[0m
```

If I click <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, it just deletes the needed file.

Is there a way to skip this prompt?

I searched the internet, and tried all buttons. Also I can't write in that `.BAT` file.